# SUM doesn't return expected result in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query that works well when all tables are populated with datas, but doesn't return expected result when 1 of them are empty.

See the problem in action:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d7ca1/1

The query should return me `240` because I have 2 item at `120`.

The query is working when `___ApplicableTaxes` is populated with datas but in my reality it's not always the case :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de1840/1

My actual query is:

```
SELECT BIL_Status
    , SUM(BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity) BIL_RateNonTaxed
    , IFNULL(SUM((BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity)+(BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity*total_sales_tax/100)), SUM(BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity)) BIL_RateTaxed 
    FROM 
    ( SELECT b.*
            , SUM(t.STX_Amount) total_sales_tax 
        FROM ___BillableDatas b 
        LEFT JOIN ___ApplicableTaxes bt 
            ON bt.ATX_BILId = b.BIL_Id 
        LEFT JOIN ___SalesTaxes t 
            ON t.STX_Id = bt.ATX_STXId 
        GROUP  
            BY ATX_BILId
     ) x
WHERE BIL_BookingId=1
GROUP 
    BY BIL_Status
```

What I'm missing here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your empty table `___ApplicableTaxes` is the middleman between `___BillableDatas` and `___SalesTaxes` and it is empty. What did you expect?

Comment: I expected to have the sum of `___BillableDatas` even if not data are in `___ApplicableTaxes`.